# Query for post and comments all in one?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

I've been reading about hierarchical database structure and am wondering how I can apply it to my current code.  At the moment, I am querying for all posts, then in the loop for that query, I do another query for all comments for that post.  So an extra query for every post; that seems inefficient to me.  My table structure:

posts.id, posts.userid, posts.text

comments.id,comments.postid,comments.userid,comments.text

I saw some posts where people mention doing all this in one query, where the returned query uses sql's CONCAT() to add spaces to indent comments.  Then in appcode you'd check for spaces and display accordingly.  Any ideas on a query for my data style?

Answer (score 1):

you can concat any fields you like, but it will be messy to concat the comments.text rows

what i normally do is put posts and comments in the same table:
posts (postid, userid, text, parent_postid)

you know if it's a post when parent_postid == 0, and you can easily fetch all posts/comments for the same "post"
i think is a more common way in most systems

Comment: Interesting.  Well even though I have 2 tables, the theory is the same; I could just LEFT JOIN the comments table and CONCAT the comments so I know they're comments in the display.

EDIT: Wouldn't this give you too much redundant data (post text etc) ?

Comment: when you'll LEFT JOIN, you will get the columns from both tables - you will have the data for the selected post in all rows

Comment: Correct.  But I'm wondering if this way is better than 2 queries. I suppose doing it in 1 query would be more efficient, regardless